# C# Generic List Of Generic Objects

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I'm trying to make a list of a generic objects which will hold different types of forms controls in a generic list.  I'm not an expert in generics and have never used a generic list of generic objects before.  The examples I've found so far haven't been of much help to me.

The UIObject class :

```
public class UIObject<T>
{

    public UIObject(string Name, T _Control)
    {
        ControlName = Name;
        ControlObject = _Control;

    }
    //public Type ControlType;
    public T ControlObject;
    public String ControlName;

}
```

I can create these objects like this :

```
UIObject<TextBox> UITextbox = new UIObject<TextBox>("FirstName Textbox", FirstName);
```

the UIObjectList class containing the list of UIObjects :

```
 public class UIObjectList
{

    private List<UIObject<Type>> InterfaceObjects;
    public UIObjectList()
    {
        InterfaceObjects = new List<UIObject<Type>>();

    }

    //Find an object by name.
    public T GetInterfaceObject<T>(string Name)
    {
        foreach(UIObject<T> obj in InterfaceObjects)
        {
            if (Name == obj.ControlName) {
                return obj.ControlObject;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }}
```

The UIObjectList class is where I'm having trouble. The code is a mess right now, not sure how to accomplish what I'm trying to do or if it even can be accomplished like this.  The GetInterfaceObject() function is supposed to return the UIObject which could be a textbox, a listbox, a label etc.  I'm not sure what to do for that part.

The end goal would to be able to do something like this :

```
AddRecord(InterfaceDictionary.GetInterfaceObject("FirstName Textbox").Text);
```

where InterfaceDictionary is a UIObjectList object containing the UITextbox object i created above.

Feel free to suggest a different method of accomplishing this, if this doesnt make sense.

Comment: Please include what you have read about this subject. Otherwise, this question's title is almost exactly the same as [Generic list of generic objects](//stackoverflow.com/q/19490819)

Comment: Your generic class accomplishes little.  The controls already have a name.

Comment: Each UI Element is already a Control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) which has a `Controls` property, that returns the set of controls that this control already contains.  The point being, maybe you don't need a separate/new list; you could find the parent of the controls you want, and use that as your container.

Comment: If you make a co-variant generic interface for `UIObject` you could use that with a common parent type as the type for your internal list.  But you're not going to be able to make the list spit out different types from the same method.  And wrapping controls like this seems like a bad idea anyway.